# Retrieve distinct values from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to print customer name once and all the products for each customer.My code is below.

```
 <div id="Allproducts">
 <?php
  $AllprodsRes = $conn -> query("select * from sepproducts");
  if($AllprodsRes ->num_rows > 0){
    $result = $AllprodsRes -> fetch_array(); 
  ?>
    <label for="name"><?php echo $result['name'] . " " . $result['surname']; ?></label>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php do{ ?>

  <p><?php echo $result['product_name'] . " " //$result['count']; ?></p>  
 <?php }while($result = $AllprodsRes -> fetch_array()); ?>
 </div>
```

view sepproducts

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `sepproducts` AS
    select 
        `customers`.`name` AS `name`,
        `customers`.`surname` AS `surname`,
        `custproducts`.`product_name` AS `product_name`,
        count(0) AS `count`
    from
        (`custproducts`
        join `customers` ON ((`custproducts`.`custid` = `customers`.`custid`)))
    group by `custproducts`.`product_name`
```

Any help is welcome and appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downvoted for not showing your code at least. In all probability, your problem is in the code.

Comment: Any help for question improvement is welcome.

Comment: And upvoted for adding code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can use is something like the following (assuming you use MySQLi):

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$query = $con->query('SELECT * FROM...');

$currentCustomer = null;
while ($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $name = $result['name'] . ' ' . $result['surname'];

    // Check to see if we're working with a new customer.
    if ($currentCustomer != $name) {
        echo $name . '<br />';
        $currentCustomer = $name;
    }

    echo $result['product_name'] . '<br />';
    echo $result['product_type'] . '<br />';

    // ETC.
}
?>
```

Or if you only have one customer to worry about, use the following:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$query = $con->query('SELECT * FROM...');

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $result = $query->fetch_array();

    echo $result['name'] . ' ' . $result['surname'] . '<br />';

    do {
        echo $result['product_name'] . '<br />';
        echo $result['product_type'] . '<br />';

        // ETC.
    } while ($result = $query->fetch_array());
}
?>
```

In effect, it checks if records have been found and if so, writes one result to our array $result.  We then output the customer's name OUTSIDE of the loop (so this only occurs once), then use a do...while() loop to continue through the rest of the result array.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Marios, I have amended my answer to address the case of having multiple customers.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shane.I wonder why i haven't consider that solution.Thanks again very good solution!!!I need 15+ reputation to give you a vote up.

Comment: You are very welcome. I think you can still set it as the "Accepted answer" if it worked for you. I'm glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the databse you use you could join multiple rows into a single column. Ultimately this is a display problem. I say keep doing what you are doing and in your view keep track of the current name in the loop and compare to the next name - if the name is the same ignore it, when the name differs set current_name to this new name and continue. This way each name only shows once.